# Load npz file and iterate over all the arrays

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

l have a compressed `.npz` that l load as follow :

```
results=np.load('/homes/`enter code here`scores060000.npz', encoding='bytes')
```

However, l can't iterate over the file to access array by array.

**What l have tried ?**

```
results.files()
```

['scores']

However when l make

```
results['scores'][0] # to get the first array
```

*** IndexError: too many indices for array

```
results['scores'].keys()
```

*** AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'keys'

Here is a sample of the file

'/file4/4.png': array([-1.651477  , -1.907163  , -3.1426308 ,  3.8437457 , -1.6413991 ,
        3.9418564 , -2.097484  , -4.1060033 , -5.8090167 , -0.6079367 ,
       -1.1268529 , -1.6963539 , -0.76549244, -1.3052248 ,  2.2658308 ,
       -1.247977  ,  7.906589  ,  4.1645093 , -1.2772448 ,  2.9711807 ,
       -0.68575585, -4.08245   , -4.802993  , -1.2243137 , -3.3159957 ,
       -5.2699194 ,  0.8371297 ,  0.80230814, -5.1045756 , -2.7776072 ,
       -2.5447376 , -3.2206695 , -1.6834608 ,  0.03849944, -0.24658614,
        0.84565806,  0.8182453 , -0.79316556,  1.1238738 , -2.5781393 ,
       -1.7877787 , -7.7516017 , -0.0954666 , -0.2568078 , -5.9535336 ,
        4.600506  , -0.6839486 ,  1.101945  , -4.871244  ,  0.45752206,
       -1.5437831 ,  0.39374897, -0.5242709 , -4.308458  ,  8.083314  ,
        3.428661  , -4.207958  ,  8.915849  , -0.86354035, -0.8921649 ,
       -3.0371819 , -1.4496443 , -2.869159  , -2.0725305 , -3.3047957 ,
       -2.6443558 , -1.6881287 , -2.1690493 , -1.6784476 , -3.871248  ,
        1.2377933 , -4.456587  , -7.346478  ,  1.8070494 , -1.5207015 ,
        2.2107837 ,  5.3954268 ,  0.44746792, -2.7442515 , -5.163432  ,
        0.25762084, -2.7383866 , -3.5220423 , -1.6739469 , -5.2574334 ,
        0.19439769, -0.66933227, -3.4044476 ,  1.0006926 ,  8.179258  ,
       -0.3292276 , -2.4944222 ,  0.6352347 , -4.9328766 , -3.6732411 ,
       -4.645098  , -3.7336316 , -4.650411  , -1.1193942 , -2.4021673 ,
        9.60228   ], dtype=float32), '/file3/3.png': array([-4.950835  , -4.869176  , -1.6227134 , -0.83657277, -3.1601653 ,
        0.8242829 ,  1.6684622 , -3.7665265 ,  2.0375075 , -6.6443377 ,
        1.5364946 , -1.1193827 , -3.0785651 , -5.0486474 , -1.0922289 ,
        2.1312854 , -2.9272187 ,  0.9454415 , -0.13194042, -0.3385026 ,
       -4.4860635 , -0.80675066,  5.478806  , -1.9646504 , -1.3469064 ,
       -0.98173124, -6.078044  , -0.6684527 ,  4.5297656 ,  2.5620239 ,
       12.816556  ,  2.2342243 , -1.8920712 , -2.387616  ,  0.77336925,
        1.0052404 , -2.7040641 ,  5.7424645 , -1.1701487 , -1.2083752 ,
        2.7204783 , -5.1847005 , -3.7228272 , -0.22128446,  1.5531254 ,
       -4.013649  , -1.1326185 , -2.685383  , -1.6641728 , -0.36011285,
       -0.7170791 , -1.417088  , -2.8416286 , -1.0756694 ,  2.9484415 ,
       -3.2145221 ,  0.18724221, -4.410981  , -0.20475249, -4.284647  ,
       -0.0297867 ,  2.5260768 ,  0.8918827 , -1.1881785 , -3.121708  ,
       -5.6494484 , -2.044363  , -4.5841136 , -4.6920342 , -2.0244665 ,
       -1.060093  , -0.6903727 , -0.720652  , -4.2343864 , -1.9107593 ,
        6.3486543 , -0.15267012, -1.0452555 ,  0.9056848 , -1.1271408 ,
        4.928084  ,  2.3845124 , -0.28718042,  0.53633213,  6.3739076 ,
       -2.0438914 ,  1.20196   ,  1.1123928 , -4.3619947 , -1.1515617 ,
        0.18415602, -0.06180171, -0.20822835, -3.0902917 , -3.1353855 ,
        1.4377578 , -0.8310707 , -2.603929  ,  2.903148  , -0.6100564 ,
       -1.8161871 ], dtype=float32), '/file2/2.png': array([-2.8043437e-01, -6.2239873e-01, -2.0357392e+00,  4.9808624e-01,
       -1.7960895e+00, -1.8575675e+00, -1.2165427e+00, -3.6179656e-01,
       -4.3200240e+00, -2.4468222e+00,  1.3260385e+00, -2.7656777e+00,
       -2.0749898e+00, -2.5266984e+00,  1.3110629e+00,  3.9533191e+00,
        4.8012048e-01, -2.8147533e+00, -2.6557796e+00, -1.4515022e+00,
       -8.9944059e-01, -9.6252346e-01,  1.0777255e+00,  2.0491233e-01,
       -6.6335851e-01, -3.9736774e+00, -3.4321864e+00,  5.4393544e+00,
       -1.0569165e+00, -2.4446402e+00, -1.8671986e+00, -1.6519018e+00,
        1.7538584e+00, -2.5712433e+00, -7.4690372e-01,  4.6145740e-01,
       -5.5915272e-01, -7.8732646e-01, -3.3801985e+00, -2.5600529e+00,
       -3.5273430e+00, -1.5424553e+00,  1.9753126e+00,  8.4598374e-01,
       -1.5159348e+00, -3.1205835e+00,  2.8564734e+00, -1.5107436e+00,
       -3.4941616e+00, -1.3126992e+00, -1.8536948e-01,  1.7078512e+00,
       -4.2180629e+00, -3.2771609e+00,  8.9760866e+00, -4.4880909e-01,
       -6.3466039e+00,  2.0050712e+00,  2.1895382e+00, -1.9819100e+00,
       -2.4119055e+00,  9.2510238e-02, -1.9337451e+00, -1.4222538e+00,
        2.2197738e+00, -3.6818323e+00, -6.6456646e-02, -2.4740572e+00,
       -3.4280837e+00, -3.3387463e+00,  1.1384126e+00, -1.5373305e+00,
       -3.4580667e+00, -2.2388813e+00, -4.6271877e+00, -3.0023365e+00,
        4.5120735e-03, -6.9383731e+00,  5.4922276e+00,  3.6206059e+00,
        2.6019840e+00, -1.5382010e+00, -1.5167688e+00,  5.4298296e+00,
       -7.8890306e-01, -3.5365894e+00, -5.7465988e-01, -2.9401925e-01,
       -3.0376801e+00,  3.3693345e+00,  8.3250761e+00,  5.0635014e+00,
        2.7871721e+00, -3.2907157e+00, -3.4527814e+00, -4.3827205e+00,
       -6.0047526e+00,  2.0345461e-01,  1.5018797e+00,  1.5115099e+00,
       -2.3368890e+00], dtype=float32), '/file1/1.png': array([-2.880651  , -3.5033705 ,  3.7906199 , -0.30735028,  1.7049406 ,
       -2.4601865 , -2.432671  ,  3.573076  , -0.66925764, -4.9513187 ,
        3.5004294 , -3.1082163 , -2.1569846 , -4.655545  , -2.6699617 ,
       -2.0030148 , -2.5035274 , -2.0025814 , -0.37288237, -1.2053664 ,
       -1.1685671 ,  0.422138  ,  0.5124443 ,  0.7623316 , -0.8360331 ,
       -1.1486149 , -5.092014  ,  0.78394383,  1.6535784 ,  1.4055651 ,
        2.8729122 ,  1.0578096 , -2.6003664 , -4.1960926 , -2.3535116 ,
        0.46660176, -2.432323  ,  1.2694867 , -4.972548  ,  0.74941415,
        1.3963044 ,  3.5629773 , -2.4826858 , -1.5813217 , -1.4925203 ,
       -1.4314067 , -1.7682784 , -2.3176155 , -1.5388411 , -1.4064139 ,
        1.3307506 , -2.1563005 , -4.100337  , -3.9060237 ,  0.05410841,
       -1.2395332 ,  2.4205167 , -0.9115535 , -2.096323  , -1.5538993 ,
       -1.7992512 ,  0.3886638 , -0.8848116 , -1.7380404 , -1.6939284 ,
       -2.6846013 , -0.49933237, -0.03601296, -2.0352333 , -1.8516303 ,
       -3.2491822 ,  0.88307995,  1.3174123 , -2.4134717 , -0.78582317,
        2.5116985 , -2.7801507 , -1.9507023 , -0.8743777 ,  5.0220346 ,
        4.4525557 ,  3.0789425 ,  3.567525  ,  1.142694  , -0.6016274 ,
        0.8162438 ,  0.39270648,  7.590226  , -2.265852  ,  0.24908264,
       -1.8506968 ,  2.3867977 , -0.35229903,  0.22780067, -2.0359864 ,
        3.5617588 , -1.8114059 ,  0.6413014 ,  0.24592055, -1.2108788 ,
       -1.9091825 ], dtype=float32)}, dtype=object)

What l want to output ?

Access every array. For instance

```
 '/file1/1.png': array([-2.880651 , -3.5033705 , 3.7906199 , -0.30735028, 1.7049406 , -2.4601865 , -2.432671 , 3.573076 , -0.66925764, -4.9513187 , 3.5004294 , -3.1082163 , -2.1569846 , -4.655545 , -2.6699617 , -2.0030148 , -2.5035274 , -2.0025814 , -0.37288237, -1.2053664 , -1.1685671 , 0.422138 , 0.5124443 , 0.7623316 , -0.8360331 , -1.1486149 , -5.092014 , 0.78394383, 1.6535784 , 1.4055651 , 2.8729122 , 1.0578096 , -2.6003664 , -4.1960926 , -2.3535116 , 0.46660176, -2.432323 , 1.2694867 , -4.972548 , 0.74941415, 1.3963044 , 3.5629773 , -2.4826858 , -1.5813217 , -1.4925203 , -1.4314067 , -1.7682784 , -2.3176155 , -1.5388411 , -1.4064139 , 1.3307506 , -2.1563005 , -4.100337 , -3.9060237 , 0.05410841, -1.2395332 , 2.4205167 , -0.9115535 , -2.096323 , -1.5538993 , -1.7992512 , 0.3886638 , -0.8848116 , -1.7380404 , -1.6939284 , -2.6846013 , -0.49933237, -0.03601296, -2.0352333 , -1.8516303 , -3.2491822 , 0.88307995, 1.3174123 , -2.4134717 , -0.78582317, 2.5116985 , -2.7801507 , -1.9507023 , -0.8743777 , 5.0220346 , 4.4525557 , 3.0789425 , 3.567525 , 1.142694 , -0.6016274 , 0.8162438 , 0.39270648, 7.590226 , -2.265852 , 0.24908264, -1.8506968 , 2.3867977 , -0.35229903, 0.22780067, -2.0359864 , 3.5617588 , -1.8114059 , 0.6413014 , 0.24592055, -1.2108788 , -1.9091825 ], dtype=float32)
```

**EDIT**

```
for value,key in results['scores'].item():
    print(values)
```

**ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)**

However when l do the following

```
for value in results['scores'].item():  
    print(values)
```

it prints only keys

```
/file4/4.png
/file3/3.png
/file2/2.png
```

Thank you

Comment: Looks like you saved a dictionary.  `results['scores']` is an object dtype array with one element.  `results['scores'].item()` should give you that dictionary.

Comment: @hpaulj, results['scores'].item()  returns all the items. l would like something like results['scores'].item()[0], results['scores'].item()[1], results['scores'].item()[135]...

Comment: Does `item()` produce a dictionary?  If so, you need to use proper dictionary indexing to get at the values.

Comment: for value,key in results['scores'].item():
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)    however when l do the following     for value in results['scores'].item():  print(values)  it prints only keys

Comment: That's normal Python dictionary behavior.  Iteration on a dictionary produces the keys.  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques, https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects

Comment: @hpaulj, not sure because l tested that my_keys=potion2['scores'].keys()
*** AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'keys', my_values=potion2['scores'].values()
*** AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180370/discussion-between-josselin-and-hpaulj).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the hints from  @hpaulj

```
keys=[]
vals=[]   
for value in results['scores'].item():


       key=value
       values=results['scores'].item()[value]
       keys.append(key)
       vals.append(values)
my_dic=dict(zip(keys,vals))
```

Comment: Your self-answer was flagged for bad due to lack of content - you might want to add some links to relevant docu and two to five sentences of why this solved your problem - else it might get deleted. I skipped the falg-review + gave you this as hint to change it.

Comment: Essentially you've just recreated the dictionary that you started with.  That is, both `results['scores'].item()` and `my_dic` are dictionaries, possibly identical.